# MYSQL dont display results where date and time has passed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have script which displays upcoming fixtures.

Obviously when a fixture is no longer active I dont want it to be displayed amongst the active fixtures.

I came up with the following script, however Im still getting expired events displaying amongst active / future events...?

```
Select * FROM schedule 
        WHERE schedule.gameDate > CURDATE() OR
                    ( schedule.gameDate = CURDATE() and schedule.gameTime > CURTIME() )
        GROUP BY schedule.tournament
        ORDER By schedule.gameDate
```

**TABLE**

[image]

Any advise appreciated.

**EDIT**

Not sure if it is relevant but I should probably add I declared the timezone before executing the php script to fetch results.

`date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Johannesburg')`;

Comment: date and time should really be one field

Comment: What types of fields are gameTime and gameDate?

Comment: gameDate field = date, gameTime field = varchar. Can that cause a conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you do not have gameTime set to MySQL "time" type so you are comparing apples to oranges, and still getting a boolean result. if you are using something like varchar, char, or text to store the gameTime the query is still valid but won't return the results you expect. If you were using a "time" data type then your gameTime would be formatted like this:

08:35:00 instead of 8:35

hope that helps.